# Applying an IF.. Then on an array in VBA

Tags: arrays, vba, if-statement

Is it possible to apply an IF .. Then on an array in VBA? I have the following code and I am applying For Each and If on the array plaga - to count the number of occurrences for each Interval , however VBA returns "Subscript out of Range. So, I thought maybe I have to formulate this differently...

```
Option Explicit
Public plaga As Variant

Sub dort()
  Dim cMin As Double
  Dim cMax As Double
  Dim lDer As Long

  Dim plaga() As Variant
  plaga = Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("A1:A10").Value

  Call tri1(plaga)

  cMin = WorksheetFunction.Min(plaga)
  cMax = WorksheetFunction.Max(plaga)

  Dim longInter As Double
  longInter = (cMax - cMin) / 3

  Dim pla As Variant
  Dim lCom As Long

  lDer = 2

  For Each pla In plaga
    If pla < cMin + longInter Then
      lCom = 1
    Else
      For lCom = lDer To 3
        If pla < cMin + longInter * lCom Then
          lDer = lCom
          Exit For
        End If
      Next
    End If
    plaga(lCom) = plaga(lCom) + 1
  Next

  Dim Destination As Range
  Set Destination = Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("B1")
  Destination.Resize(3, 1).Value = plaga

End Sub
```

Comment: Rarely seen a VBA as poorly indented as this. I suggest you install SmartIndenter to learn to make your code readable. http://www.oaltd.co.uk/indenter/default.htm

Comment: The hint lies in the answer to the previous question that you asked...

Comment: I added the 1 in plaga(lCom, 1) = plaga(lCom, 1) + 1 and it did work, but it did not give me the results I wanted :/ The code is supposed to sort an array, and that was all right, but then it is supposed to create interval bins.. which it does not.

Comment: No, no, it does, thanks for the hint!

Comment: And thanks for the tip on the indenting, but I have excel 2011 on a mac :/

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what is going in your subroutine tri1(plaga) but here is what i think is the right rendition of your code.

```
Sub dort()
'
Dim cMin As Double
Dim cMax As Double
Dim lDer As Long
Dim plaga() As Variant
'
  ReDim Preserve plaga(10)
  plaga = Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("A1:A10").Value
  '
  Call tri1(plaga)
  '
  cMin = WorksheetFunction.Min(plaga)
  cMax = WorksheetFunction.Max(plaga)
  '
Dim longInter As Double
  longInter = (cMax - cMin) / 3
  '
Dim pla As Variant
Dim lCom As Long
  '
  lDer = 2
  '
  For Each pla In plaga
    If pla < cMin + longInter Then
      lCom = 1
    Else
      For lCom = lDer To 3
        If pla < (cMin + longInter) * lCom Then
          lDer = lCom
          Exit For
        End If
      Next
    End If
    plaga(lCom, 1) = plaga(lCom + 1, 1)
  Next
  '
Dim Destination As Range
  Set Destination = Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("B1:B1")
  Destination.Resize(3, 1).Value = plaga
'
End Sub
```

## UPDATE

Note: i've added plaga2() to show whole numbers of longinter

```
Sub dort()

    Dim cMin As Double
    Dim cMax As Double
    Dim lDer As Long
    Dim plaga() As Variant
    Dim plaga2() As Variant


    ReDim Preserve plaga(10)
    ReDim Preserve plaga2(10)
    plaga = Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("A1:A10").Value
    plaga2 = Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("A1:A10").Value

    'Call tri1(plaga)

    cMin = WorksheetFunction.Min(plaga)
    cMax = WorksheetFunction.Max(plaga)

    Dim longInter As Double
    'In this case useing the numbers you stated
    'longinter = (7 - 1)/3 = 2
    longInter = (cMax - cMin) / 3

    Dim pla As Variant
    Dim lCom As Integer
    For lCom = 1 To 10
        If plaga(lCom, 1) >= (CMin + longInter) Then
            plaga(lCom, 1) = (plaga(lCom, 1) / longInter)
            plaga2(lCom, 1) = Int(plaga(lCom, 1))
        Else
            plaga(lCom, 1) = 1
            plaga2(lCom, 1) = 1
        End If
    Next

  Dim Destination1 As Range
  Set Destination1 = Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("B1:B1")
  Destination1.Resize(10, 1).Value = plaga

  Dim Destination2 As Range
  Set Destination2 = Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("C1:C1")
  Destination2.Resize(10, 1).Value = plaga2

End Sub
```

Comment: The first line should say....I'm not sure what is going on in your subroutine tri1(plaga) but here is what i think is the right rendition of your code

Comment: My code doesn't work properly yet. The idea is that tri1 sorts the values (you can see that in a previous question I asked - Sorting procedure...). Now, I have tried to construct intervals of length longInter and to count the number of occurrences in each interval. The only problem is neither my code nor your code returns the frequencies correctly :/ 

2
3
4
5
7
3
1
2
4
1

Comment: So what should the sorted resulting values be for? would they be for intervals of longinter in each respective value?

Comment: Well, I just sorted them to get the maximum and minimum and to speed up the process. So, I start with the first element in the sorted array, which would be 1, and see if it is smaller than 3 to assign it to the counter lCom, and so on. I base myself on this http://sitestory.dk/excel_vba/histogram-vba.htm  
The problem is with the number of occurrences.. they should be 6 -3 -1 for the intervals.. while I get 5,5,3 and I can't see where this is coming from.

Comment: I'm not tryinh to construct a histogram, I just base myself on it for the frequencies.

Comment: Your result values are incorrect because, based on your data which was 1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,7 which give MAX of 7 and MIN of 1 therefore longinter is longinter=(MAX-MIN)/3 which equates to longinter(7-1=6)/3 = 2 and the maximum times 2 is in the MAX value is 3.5 so your results should really be....    .5, .5, 1, 1, 1.5, 1.5, 2, 2, 2.5 ,3.5 by my calculations

Comment: I can't see why you have obtained .5, .5, 1 etc. I should just get 3 bins - Intervals [1,3[, [3,5[, [5,7[ and assign humbers to them. So, 1 and 2 occur 4 times, so my new column on excel should display 4, then similarly for [3,5[ and 2 for [5,7[. Except on excel I get 5, 5, 3 in the column (with my code).

Comment: Sorry I thought you wanted the individual results, and after reading the link I can see you want the TOTAL values so if you run the updated sample the totals of the values (6x1, 3x2, and 1x3) are there individually you justhave to plonk them into a format you want. I arrived at the point 5 etc values using decimals not WHOLE numbers

Comment: Exactly! Ok, going to try it now.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm really lost, I can't see how to display that :S

Comment: Lets take this to chat as otherwise we will end up with lots of comments with chatting in them (my room is called zaf khan chat with seigna)